# Overlaying PNG images KEEPING transparency

Tags: c#, png, transparency

So basically what I want to do is overlap two .PNG images with transparent backgrounds. One is with a shotgun which rotates to mouse position, and the other is a cartoon character which I want to put behind the shotgun. Now, the problem is everytime I overlap them, the transparent background of the PNG image gets in the way and I can't see the shooter at all.

I have tried putting the shooter in a panel but placing the shotgun picturebox within it screws up the rotation algorithm (makes it rotate very slowly), I have no idea why.

Any help would be apreciated, thanks.

Coding I used:
Rotation algorithm:

```
private Bitmap rotateImage(Bitmap b, float angle)
{
    //create a new empty bitmap to hold rotated image
    Bitmap returnBitmap = new Bitmap(b.Width, b.Height);
    //make a graphics object from the empty bitmap
    Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(returnBitmap);
    //move rotation point to center of image
    g.TranslateTransform((float)b.Width / 2, (float)b.Height / 2);
    //rotate
    g.RotateTransform((int)angle);
    //move image back
    g.TranslateTransform(-(float)b.Width / 2, -(float)b.Height / 2);
    //draw passed in image onto graphics object
    g.DrawImage(b, new Point(0, 0)); //???
    return returnBitmap;
}

private float CalcAngle(Point TargetPos)
{
    Point ZeroPoint = new Point(pictureBox1.Location.X + pictureBox1.Width / 2, pictureBox1.Location.Y + pictureBox1.Height / 2);
    if (TargetPos == ZeroPoint)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    double angle;
    double deltaX, deltaY;

    deltaY = TargetPos.Y - ZeroPoint.Y;
    deltaX = TargetPos.X - ZeroPoint.X;

    angle = Math.Atan2(deltaY, deltaX) * 180 / Math.PI;
    return (float)angle;
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pictureBox1.Image = (Bitmap)backup.Clone();
    //Load an image in from a file
    Image image = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image);
    //Set our picture box to that image
    pictureBox1.Image = (Bitmap)backup.Clone();

    //Store our old image so we can delete it
    Image oldImage = pictureBox1.Image;
    //Set angle
    angle = CalcAngle(new Point(Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y - 10));
    //Pass in our original image and return a new image rotated X degrees right
    pictureBox1.Image = rotateImage((Bitmap)image, angle);
    if (oldImage != null)
    {
        oldImage.Dispose();
        image.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: Attach some of the code snippets you have tried so far

Comment: I've put up the rotation algorithm, and as for the transparency thing, i haven't implemented any code for it yet (the panel thing i did from the form editor).

Answer (score 0):

When you are creating a new Bitmap try to use any of the pixel format for 32 bpp or 64 bpp. See the code below:

```
Bitmap returnBitmap = new Bitmap(b.Width, b.Height, PixelFormat.Format64bppPArgb);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I draw three different png files on top of each other onto a panel:

```
using (Graphics graphic = panel1.CreateGraphics())
{
  using (Image image = Image.FromFile(@"D:\tp3.png")) graphic.DrawImage(image, Point.Empty);
  using (Image image = Image.FromFile(@"D:\tp2.png")) graphic.DrawImage(image, Point.Empty);
  using (Image image = Image.FromFile(@"D:\tp1.png")) graphic.DrawImage(image, Point.Empty);
}
```

If you create a new BitMap do as @Palak.Maheria said and use a 32bit format with an alpha channel!

Comment: Thanks :) had to to some more research on the DrawImage function and I did not use the panel, but your answer helped a lot. Regards :)